# externalfigure with file name in a command in ConTeXt

Tags: macros, graphics, context

Is it possible to store an image file name in a command?

The first \externalfigure works, the second one doesn't:

```
\define\iii{img/ic ia super small.PNG}

\setlayer[letterhead_front_page]    % name of the layer
    [hoffset=1cm,offset=0.5cm]  % placement (from upper left corner of the layer)
    {
    \framed[frame=on,  height=2cm]
        {
        \externalfigure[img/ic ia super small.PNG]      
        }
    
       
    }  
    
    [hoffset=0.5cm,offset=8cm]  % placement (from upper left corner of the layer)
    {
    \framed[frame=on,  height=2cm]
        {
        \externalfigure[\iii]       
        }
    
       
    }
```

This is how the second image renders:
[image: image rendering]

Comment: Use `\defineexpandable` or just `\def` instead.

Comment: Thanks,  That worked.  I could not find document on \define \defineexandable or \def in the index of the Context reference manual.   

Can you suggest where i should be looking to understand these?

Comment: `\def` is a TeX primitive, so it works the same in LaTeX and ConTeXt. Any TeX manual should be useful. See [this](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/plain/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf). About `\define` and `\defineexpandable`, see [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/define).